# Problema en Password verify

Tags: php

Amigos quisiera saber por que en mi condición `IF` por mas que haga siempre lo reconoce como false, he verificado y realiza la consulta correctamente, la conexión correctamente y el array que trae es el siguiente:

```
Array ( [IDUSUARIO] => 1 [USUARIO] => admin [CONTRASENIA] => admin )
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal aparte de haber nacido? xdxd ayuda por favor.

Los datos de la base de datos, host, usuario y contraseña son remotos, lo estoy haciendo en el servidor de `HOSTINGER`.

```
<?php

$host_db = "xxxxx";
$user_db = "xxxxxx";
$pass_db = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxx";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 print("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO = '$username'";

$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     

 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 }
 if (password_verify($password, $row['CONTRASENIA'])){ 

    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    print "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
    print "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>"; 

 }else{ 
   print "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
  print_r($row);
     print "<br><a href='index.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hola @CarlosHernández. ¿Podrías **[edit]** la pregunta mostrando el valor exacto que se obtiene de `$row['CONTRASENIA']`?

Comment: Lo he probado en local con mis datos y funciona correctamente. Como nota y si está comprobada la conexión y la consulta... 1.- ¿que llega por `post`? comprobar si son los datos que esperas. 2.- el `password` (`$row['CONTRASENIA']`) debería estar generado mediante `password_hash`, imagino que si, pero no se ha comentado nada al respecto. 3.- Se recomienda usar `password_needs_rehash` por si cambia algo en el algoritmo actual de generación de `hash` en comparación con el que se usó para generar el `password` que se está comprobando.

Comment: El usuario y contraseña los registro directamente desde la base de datos, entonces yo creo que ese es el problema ya que no lo guardo como hash

Comment: Ya lo guardé como hash el password cuando lo registro e igual me sigue apareciendo el mismo problema xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claramente tu error es :

En la base de datos contraseña es `admin` no esta en ningun momento hecho con `password_hash` y si leemos la documentacion de php nos dice :

> boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
>   ***Comprueba que el hash*** proporcionado coincida con la contraseña
>   facilitada.

Claramente lo que tu estas comparando es admin y admin, en ningun momento generas un `hash`.

Cuando crees un usuario, guarda su contraseña con `password_hash`

```
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Como en tu base de datos va a quedar la password como un `hash` simplemente haces eso :

```
if (password_verify($password_post, $row['CONTRASENIA'])) {
```

Comment: Mencionar que si deja el algoritmo a `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` y la gente de PHP decide en un momento dado cambiarlo de `bcrypt` a otro dará problemas (y bastante graves). Lo suyo es especificar explícitamente cual quieres usar.

Comment: @kerunaru toda la razon, sin embargo si se decide cambiar por otro tipo de encriptacion deben tener consciente que en password generados anteriormente habra conflictos

Comment: Ya he guardado el password como hash, sin embargo me sigue apareciendo el mismo error al momento de logearme D:

Comment: Cuando ingresas admin como password , haces password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);?

Comment: Si ya lo hice de la siguiente manera $hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: puedes imprimir el hash que te devuelve $hash? y compararlo con la de la base de datos?

Comment: no habrá algún problema por el cotejamiento de la DB? ya que los campos y la BD llevan cotejamiento utf8_general_ci

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50636/discussion-between-sioesi-and-carlos-hernandez).